# PHP rand function giving empty values - still not working

Tags: php

I have  this little tid-bit of my code, which is eventually sent to a MySQL database. The rest of the code is sound, but this code likes to give me empty data some of the time. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Edit: Here's the whole chunk

```
//random Species
$sp_one = mt_rand(1,10);    
$one_species = "Water Leaper";

//random Genetics

if($one_species == "Water Leaper")
{
    $one_gene = mt_rand(1,5);

    if($one_gene < 3)
    {
        $one_genetics = "1";
    }

    else if($one_gene < 5)
    {
        $one_genetics = "2";
    }

    else
    {
        $one_genetics = "3";
    }
}

//random Gender
$one_sex_num = mt_rand(1,2);

if($one_sex_num == 1)
{
    $one_gender = "Female";
}

if($one_sex_num == 2)
{
    $one_gender = "Male";
}

//Entering it
$sql="INSERT INTO creatures (species, sex, location, genetics)
VALUES('{$one_species}','{$one_gender}', 's1','{$one_genetics}')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: Where is the empty data situated ?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by *give me empty data some of the time*, especially, what are the values of `$one_gene` and `$one_genetics` after the code gave you empty data.

Comment: In a MySQL table column. It pops up randomly and causes errors on my site that I have to go and fix manually.

Comment: That problem is unrelated to this code. Check the code that inserts the data into the database for errors, and post here if necessary.

Comment: why are doing a rand between 1 a 5 if you only want a number between 1 and 3?

Comment: Matias, perhaps for statistical reasons. The OP's code will generate 1 or 2 more often than 3.

Comment: @Matías Maybe it is intended that the probability of getting "3" is only half that of getting "1" or "2".

Comment: Yeah, I want the third to be the rarest kind. And I think it is fixed. I'll close it soon. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: You posted more irrelevant code.... :(

Comment: I was asked to show more code to try to get to the root of the issue

Comment: Oke what are you trying to do??? I don't get it at all. Are you making some random animal picker!??

Comment: Yeah, I am. It selects a random species, which I have only one of at the moment, and then it chooses a random gene for it.

Comment: Oke than you can better use object or array to store animals in and then pick a random number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your if clauses seem a bit redundant. More concise code:

```
if ($one_gene <3)      { $one_genetics = "1"; }
elseif ($one_gene <5)  { $one_genetics = "2"; }
else                   { $one_genetics = "3"; }
```

This should always return a value - if everything else fails, `"3"`.

Maybe better even:

```
$one_genetics = ($one_gene + 1) / 2; // integer division
```

Comment: Great - you have discovered that the error is elsewhere! Please accept the answer and post a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing exacly but maby you can take a look at this:

```
<?php

    $animals = array();

    $animals[] = array('dog', 78, array('Komondor','Old English Sheepdog'));    
    $animals[] = array('Drosophila', 8, array('Vestigal','Ebony')); 

    $number_animals = count($animals) - 1;
    $list_size = 30;

    for($q = 1; $q <= $list_size; $q++){

        $rand = rand(0, $number_animals);
        $animal = $animals[$rand];

        $number_species = count($animal[2]) - 1;

        $rand = rand(0, $number_species);
        $randsex = rand(0, 1);

        $species = $animal[2][$rand];
        $sex = ($randsex ? 'male' : 'female');
        $genes = $animal[1];

        echo "$q: $species - $sex - $genes <br>";
    }

?>
```

See a live demo at: [here](http://paperboat.tk/test/random%20animal%20gene%20picker/)

It pics random animals with specs if you want you can modify to your own wishes.